# Poincaré dual of $H^1(M,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ for a $\frac{\mathbb{CP}^2\times S^1}{\tau}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology, geometric-topology, quotient-spaces

Given a $M=\frac{\mathbb{CP}^2\times S^1}{\tau}$, where $τ$ acts as $−1$ on the sphere $S^1$ and a complex conjugation on complex projective space $\mathbb{CP}^2$. See [Dold, Albrecht (1956), "Erzeugende der Thomschen Algebra N", Mathematische Zeitschrift, 65 (1): 25–35, doi:10.1007/BF01473868](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01473868).

I think that
$$H^1(M,\mathbb{Z}_2)=\mathbb{Z}_2.$$
Let us call the generator as $L$.

what is the Poincaré dual (PD) of this generator $L$ for $H^1(M,\mathbb{Z}_2)$, say PD($L$) as a 4-manifold?

Is this PD($L$)=$\mathbb{CP}^2$?